# Deleting a folder of product images other than img/p/ ? Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I take in charge the reconstruction of an old Prestashop website. I am a newbie with this CMS and its files structure is still not clear in my mind.

When I copied the website from the live server to my localhost, I have the size of the `img` folder equal to 4.5Gb, but I noticed that I have a folder with a name: `p_old` with 1.75 Gb size.

The folder `p` is 2.8Gb size. According Prestashop documentation, this folder is by default the place where Prestashop put the uploaded pictures for the products.

As you know, optimizing the hard space used by the website has many paybacks (upload time, hosting server quota..). However, I cannot delete the `p_old` folder without asking experts (I am afraid the files inside are still used somewhere in the website).What do you think about it?

Your usual help and time are so much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p-old folder was manually named and/or renamed. PrestaShop hosts all of it's images in the img/p/ folder. Make sure to backup before any deletion. You should check your Preferences>Images and inspect the element of all pictures on the website to make sure it is all coming form the p folder and not the p-old folder.

Comment: That is exactly what I am thinking. I performed backup, but for the individual check I cannot do a comprehensive one since the number of products is more than 1400. +1 till I make sure no one gives another idea. Thanks man and good regards.

Comment: Hey, no problem. I hope it helps. In this situation the best thing to do is to spend a couple hours looking at different Category, Product, Banner, Slideshow pictures etc... inspecting the element to make sure it is all coming from the same p folder. Keep it going for PrestaShop, 1.6 is really something special. :)

Comment: I agree with you, especially for the last sentence. It is the first time I work with PS, and I took in charge reconstruction (including upgrade from 1.4.4.1 to 1.6.0.6). I claim a lot of enhancements have been added bwtween the two versions. Thanks again and have a nice day.